# ExtJS Default Headers (token authorization) Page Refresh

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I have my ExtJS application that on success login I set an Authorization Token so I can send that on every Ajax Call to my server:

```
success: function (response, opts)
                {
                    var obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);

                    // set authToken
                    util.Util.authToken = obj.data.SessionId;

                    Ext.Ajax.defaultHeaders = {
                        'Authorization': 'Token' + obj.data.SessionId
                    };
```

It's working great. Now I implement Ext.ux.Router so I can refresh my browser and I can stay where I was, but I realize that when my browser refresh I loose my **defaultHeader** token.

Any clue on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about save this `SessionId` in cookie? And if it exists - use it, otherwise send request.

Comment: Do you recommend to encrypt that session on the cookie?

Comment: You know - the best way is to be to protect your session to be stolen. That's why it is a good idea to set session cookies as [httponly](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-httponly). So the best way is to don't do as you want :) I don't see any advantages to encrypt that `SessionId` in that cookie.